# PKPassLibrary not functioning

Tags: ios, objective-c, passbook

I am using PKPassLibrary to determine the count of passes in the passbook app.:

```
if ([PKPassLibrary isPassLibraryAvailable]) {
  PKPassLibrary * passLib = [[PKPassLibrary alloc] init];
  NSLog(@"Count of passes: %i", [passLib passes].count);
}
```

The output is always **"Count of passes: 0"** even when if there are some passes in the passbook, for example from www.coupons.com. I am developing on iPhone 4, iOS 6.1.2

Does anyone have the same problem?

EDIT: found the reason on [How to access passes from passbook in my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14017551/how-to-access-passes-from-passbook-in-my-app/14026170#14026170) :(

Comment: If you found the answer answer your own question and mark it as correct so it's no longer in the unanswered section

Comment: Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. So I will answer in 7 hours. ;)

Comment: the reason for this behavior is described on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14017551/how-to-access-passes-from-passbook-in-my-app/14026170#14026170

Comment: @PhilippLi I had the same issue, How could you achieve ? I have seen the above link, And also followed it, Still not working, Could you please know me the steps of it ?